# Can't route traffic through home VPN

Tags: vpn, router, openvpn

Small disclaimer: I'd much rather ask this question in forums.openvpn.net but it appears that the registration page is busted...

I'm trying to set up my home router (an Asus RT-AX55) to act as a VPN server, offering me secure internet access if I'm using, say, a public Wifi at a hotel or something.

Initially I had some issues with the certificates that came pre-installed by the router (too old and, apparently, too short, causing most OpenVPN clients to complain of lax security). I've managed to resolve that and now I'm able to establish a connection just fine.

However, I've found that while I am able to establish a connection and access resources on my home LAN (like accessing the router's configuration page or connecting over SSH to the router itself) I cannot actually browse the internet. I've verified this both from a laptop hooked up to another network as well as my Android phone (I'm using [OpenVPN for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn)).

As such I'm fairly certain the problem is likely server-side. Here's the config.ovpn contents taken from the router via SSH:

```
# Automatically generated configuration

# Tunnel options
proto udp4
multihome
port 1194
dev tun21
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
keepalive 10 30
up '/etc/openvpn/ovpn-up'
down '/etc/openvpn/ovpn-down'
setenv ovpn_type 0
setenv unit 1
script-security 2
daemon vpnserver1
verb 3
status-version 2
status status 10
compress lzo
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn

# Server Mode
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
duplicate-cn
push "route 192.168.50.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway 500"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.50.200"

# Data Channel Encryption Options
auth SHA1
cipher AES-128-CBC

# TLS Mode Options
ca ca.crt
dh dh.pem
cert server.crt
key server.key

# Custom Configuration
```

Yes - the first line clearly states the configuration is automatically generated (likely via the router configuration page), so editing the file probably won't work long-term. However, I can't see any major faults of this configuration that would pop up at me that would explain the lack of internet connectivity.

Is there anything this configuration is missing that should be added so that I could use the home router as a gateway for accessing the internet? If I know what setting is missing I can either add it using the `Custom configuration` section (GUI has a text-field for this) or just play around with the GUI settings with the hope that one of the settings is what I'm looking for...

EDIT:

I was thinking this could be something to do with the routing on the router itself. Here's the routing table, but it also looks OK to me...

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags    Metric Ref    Use Type Iface
default         <WAN GW>        0.0.0.0         UG       0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
1.0.0.1         <WAN GW>        255.255.255.255 UGH      1      0        0 WAN0 eth0
1.1.1.1         <WAN GW>        255.255.255.255 UGH      1      0        0 WAN0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun21
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0      tun21
<WAN broadcast> *               255.255.255.252 U        0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
<WAN GW>        *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
192.168.50.0    *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
```

EDIT 2:

More strangeness when I try to ping stuff from my laptop when the OpenVPN connection is active. I can ping and receive responses fine. I can ping known IP addresses such as 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8, and it seems DNS resolution is also working fine (`nslookup` returns sensible results). However, attempting to open a web page in any browser will fail (PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest` will fail as well).

`tracert` also seems to show sensible results, with the OpenVPN IP range being the first hop (10.8.0.1) and continuing through my ISPs devices (at least judging by the resolved names that contain the ISP name).

For the record, I do not think it's my ISP blocking anything. I was able to set up an IPSec VPN from the router and that works without any issues (it's more annoying to set up, however, both on Windows and Android, so I'd still rather get OpenVPN working).

I've also double checked the WiFi settings on both the phone and the laptop - everything's standard with DHCP-assigned IPs and DNS servers. But it's worth noting that the issues on the Android phone occur even when using a mobile data plan (rather than a public WiFi) which very strongly points to a configuration issue on the server / router.

EDIT 3:

It appears I can access web pages via IPs (if a site allows this). So, for example, I can access 1.1.1.1 when I'm connected via VPN. I've disabled pushing the routers DNS and instead I tried pushing 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8... alas, just like before, while I can ping and resolve names just fine I can't actually connect to any URLs.

Comment: There are quite a few things that could be tripping you up.  My guess is NAT, but it could also be DNS, routing or something else.   is your router NAT'ing packets from 10.8.0.0/24 or wider?  What does a traceroute show? What does your vpn client routing table look like?  Can you ping 8.8.8.8 from the client?

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for the comment suggesting pings and traceroute. I completely forgot to include those. See second edit of the question for more details.

Comment: This sounds like a DNS issue - what happens if you browse to "http://202.14.102.1" ?  (That is an old site - it talks about "KC Internet".   If that works the problem is likely DNS related - in which case, try forcing DNS to ise 1.1.1.1 on your vpn client and see if things work (eg browse to https://www.whatismyip.com and see if your home IP address comes up) - if it does, we have narrowed down the problem to DNS.

Comment: the editor does not what to let me do that test url properly  - it needs to be http : // 202.14.102.1

Comment: @davidgo You are correct. I was able to access 1.1.1.1 as well as the page you suggested. But DNS names ARE getting resolved, so I find this most peculiar! I guess I could change the config to push 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 as the DNS server for the VPN, and see if that helps...

Comment: @davidgo I've been playing around some more. For a moment I thought this really IS just a DNS issue, and I can ignore the home-router DNS and just leave it at that. So I disabled the existing DNS config line and added my own (`push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"`). Unfortunately the issue is just as it was. I can access sites by their IPs. I can resolve names. I can ping IPs and names. I still can't open URLs.

Comment: At this point Im not sure I can help, as I dont know enougj about your router.  (I suspect you may be able to do something similar) - at this point on my dd-wrt router I'd be breaking out the heavy artillary, using tcpdump to trace packets, and also using iptables rules to inspect and modify the firewall - especially NAT.  (it almost looks like a NAT bug on the firewall to me)

Comment: @davidgo What kind of NAT setting would permit accessing sites by their IP, but not their URL? I mean, if this is a NAT issue, then wouldn't IP-based sites be inaccessible as well? Or do you mean a literal bug, as in the firmware being borked?

Comment: General FYIs: `user nobody` and `group nogroup` aren't being used, which prevents privilege escalation attacks; `duplicate-cn` is not secure - use SANs; `auth SHA1` is not secure - instead use `SHA256` || `SHA512` _(x64 CPUs process `SHA512` faster than `SHA256`)_; `verb 4` is ideal since it makes troubleshooting more efficient _(e.g. changing to `4` and restarting the server when needing to troubleshoot is inefficient - ideal for client is `5`)_; `tls-crypt` is not being used, which helps to prevent MITM attacks; for throughput, ensure a GCM TLS cipher is being used via the server log

Comment: I have no idea.  What yoy describe makes no sense at all, but based on what you have said the problem must be with dns (or DoH), packet forwarding or NAT, so tjose are the places to look. Maybe the problem relates to hairpun NAT implementation or a firmware bug firewalling this routers web interface from the WAN port...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact same issue on RT-AX55. It drove me nuts, until I figured it out, that the culprit is AiProtection. I turned it off and magic, everything works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).